# How to send JSON and retrieve it using cURL?

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

This link = `http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***`

will return this list of JSON :

[image]

I've already tested by :

- Navigate to `http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***` through a browser
- And make a curl request via command line `$ curl http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***`
- either way will give return the JSON, and give me the same result.
- Well, what I can tell by that is my `$array` is storing something in it.
- Even if I did `dd($array)` - I still get the same result.

### Here is what I've

---

Here is how I establish my JSON

```
public function index_2(){

    $file_name = 'inventory.csv';
    $file_path = 'C:\\QuickBooks\\'.$file_name;
    $csv= file_get_contents($file_path);
    $utf8_csv = utf8_encode($csv);
    $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $utf8_csv));

    return Response::json($array);

}
```

---

Here is how I make a cURL request and trying to retrieve that JSON

```
<?php 

    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:*****");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json_decode = json_decode($array, TRUE);
```

I keep getting complaint that $array variable is not define, but in fact I did define and send it over like this `return Response::json($array);` .

[image]

I am not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: How about `json_decode($body)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$body = curl_exec($ch);
^^^^^

$json_decode = json_decode($array, TRUE);
                           ^^^^^^
```